# yii2 file required custom validation

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have a form where the required validation rules for the fields can be configures and stored in the model.

When rendering the form, I create the validation rules as follows (simplified) which works fine.

```
$view_parameters = $competition_article->view_parameters;

if (!empty($view_parameters) && is_array($view_parameters)) {

    foreach ($view_parameters as $parameter_key => $parameter_value) {

       $field_name = $parameter_value['name'];
       $field_required = $parameter_value['required'];

       if ($field_required) {
            Validator::createValidator('required', $model, [$field_name]);
       }

    }

}
```

For the form submission, I use a custom validation rule. This works for all but the file attachment.

```
    public function rules()
    {
        $rules =  [
   
   
            [['firstname', 'surname', 'closeststore', 'email', 'phone', 'response', 'attachment'],
             'dynamicValidator',
             'skipOnEmpty' => false 
            ],

            [['attachment'], 'file', 
             'extensions' => 'pdf, jpeg, jpg, doc, docx', 
              'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false
            ],

        ];

        return $rules;

    }
```

On the custom validation method, I handle the file separately.
I tried
a) addError() and return false
b) createValidator() and validateAttribute() pair , which works for the text fields.

```
    public function dynamicValidator($attribute, $params, $validator )
    {

        $view_parameters = $this->view_parameters;

        if ($view_parameters[$attribute]['required'])

            $validator = new Validator();

            if ($attribute == 'attachment') {
                if (empty($_FILES['CompetitionForm']['name']['attachment']))
[$attribute]);
                $this->addError( $attribute, 'Please include your attachment to enter.');
                // NOTE : Adding the validator has no effect
                // $validator =  $validator->createValidator('required', $this,               
                // $validator->validateAttribute($this, $attribute);

                return false;

            }

            $validator =  $validator->createValidator('required', $this, [$attribute]);

            $validator->validateAttribute($this, $attribute);

        }


    }
```

Despite the code being reached, an error is not raised when the attachment is require and the either the addError() or createValidator() is called.

How can I fail the validation when no file is attached and the attachment is required?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this validation rules for attachment using skipOnEmpty.

```
[['attachment'], 'file', 
 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 
 'extensions' => 'pdf, jpeg, jpg, doc, docx', 
 'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false
 ],
```